# Are there any mature command line JDBC clients?

Tags: jdbc, command-line, command-line-interface

I am trying to create a set of test scripts that will perform black-box testing of something that works with database. For that I need to issue SQL commands from standard input or file, which was quite possible with "mysql" client, but now we use other database, which has only jdbc driver. I need the same basic functionality in command line as mysql client has, but for any jdbc powered database. Is that possible without programming my custom java tool?

Comment: You can try this open source tool http://sourceforge.net/projects/jdbcsql/

Answer (score 11):

This one is pretty commonly used, works with any SQL database, and is pretty well supported: https://github.com/julianhyde/sqlline

Comment: normally you shouldn't post links in answers because they could go bad but for this question its the only way to answer it

Comment: @johnny5, that's true, but it's only because the question itself is off-topic - _"Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow"_

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie yeah I already marked it as that before but i needed to make a comment because i was in the review queues, and you know how tricky their tests are

Answer (score 8):

I've had success with jisql for Oracle and Postgres databases, and it appears to support most databases with JDBC drivers:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jisql/

Comment: nice, but cackspace command does not work in linux machine. I can remove wronly typed commands by Delete command

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean something like http://web.quuxo.com/products/jdbctool/ ?

**Edit 6/22:** How about HenPlus then: http://henplus.sourceforge.net/ ?

Comment: Yes, but jdbctool supports only one db type: "Currently, only HSQLDB is supported." Even if apropriate driver is in classpath, jdbctool is in no help.

Comment: I added another possible option

Comment: Seems that henplus moved onto [github](https://github.com/neurolabs/henplus). Wish it was more active